# Temporarily Make It So Nothing is Selected on Mouse Move While Mouse Down

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mouse, mouseevent

I've created a custom drag event, but unfortunately when I am dragging my div around all of the text on the page is being selected where I drag. I've tried this so far:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

This isn't doing it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drag starts with the `mousedown` event.

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e){e.preventDefault();});
```

Comment: You are a god among insects, never let anyone tell you different.

Comment: @Kirk, I quite enjoyed that ego-boost.